# How to combine object properties in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to know the best way to do this, say I have two objects

```
var objectA = {
    propertyA: 1,
    propertyB: 2
    ...
    propertyM: 13
}

var objectB = {
    propertyN: 14,
    propertyO: 15
    ...
    propertyZ: 26
}
```

If objectC is created by

```
var objectC = Object.assign(objectA, objectB);
```

How can I declare/describe objectC, so the compiler/IDE knows that it has the properties of both objectA and objectB?

I'd like to find a way without the need of defining interfaces for objectA and objectB. I don't want to write declaration and definition/evaluation for the same property twice. This redundancy is significant if I have too many properties on an object.

(Is there an operator that can extract the interface/type of an existing object?)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 278, accepted):

Seems like this should do the trick:

```
var objectA = {
    propertyA: 1,
    propertyB: 2,
    .
    . // more properties here
    .
    propertyM: 13
};

var objectB = {
    propertyN: 14,
    propertyO: 15,
    .
    . // more properties here
    .
    propertyZ: 26
};

var objectC = {...objectA, ...objectB}; // this is the answer

var a = objectC.propertyA;

var n = objectC.propertyN;
```

Based on this article: https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/12/23/typescript-2-1-object-rest-and-spread

---

In addition, the order of the variables in the decomposition matters.
Consider the following:

```
var objectA = {
    propertyA: 1,
    propertyB: 2, // same property exists in objectB
    propertyC: 3
};

var objectB = {
    propertyX: 'a',
    propertyB: 'b', // same property exists in objectA
    propertyZ: 'c'
};

// objectB will override existing properties, with the same name,
// from the decomposition of objectA
var objectC = {...objectA, ...objectB}; 

// result: 'b'
console.log(objectC.propertyB); 

// objectA will override existing properties, with the same name,
// from the decomposition of objectB
var objectD = {...objectB, ...objectA}; 

// result: '2'
console.log(objectD.propertyB);
```

Comment: just to improve the answer: this line does the trick: var objectC = {...objectA, ...objectB};

Comment: I want to update property of objectA if same key exist in both object. Means if key is same then it should take property of objectB. How is it possible?

Comment: Read the comments in my answer. Basically it constructs properties from left to right, where each new information overrides the existing one: `var objectC = {...objectA, ...objectB};`. Properties form `objectB` will override properties that were already assigned from `objectA`, if properties have the same name.

Comment: This works, therefore answers OP, however my concern is there is no type associated now to objectD or objectC  , when you try to explicitly type it to something (assume there is such a type), it wont work. Is there type safe way of doing this ?

Comment: @SrivathsaHarishVenkataramana the types are inferred from the assignment. So objectC will have `propertyB: string`, while objectD will infer it as `propertyB: number`. You could manually type both C & D: `type ABC = { propertyA: number; propertyB: string | number; propertyC: number; propertyX: string; propertyZ: string; }` or just one of them by setting propertyB to string or to number.

Answer (score 18):

> (Is there an operator that can extract the interface/type of an
>   existing object? Is it possible?)

You should go for *typeof*.

```
type typeA = typeof objectA;
type typeB = typeof objectB;
```

To get them merged you can use intersection operation as basarat already pointed out.

```
type typeC = typeA & typeB
```

Answer (score 12):

> so the compiler/IDE knows that it has the properties of both objectA and objectB?

Use an intersection type + generics. E.g. [from here](https://github.com/alm-tools/alm/blob/f8d597374437cbc5911f0cabe26124a29d8eaa11/src/common/utils.ts#L403-L419)

```
/**
 * Quick and dirty shallow extend
 */
export function extend<A>(a: A): A;
export function extend<A, B>(a: A, b: B): A & B;
export function extend<A, B, C>(a: A, b: B, c: C): A & B & C;
export function extend<A, B, C, D>(a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D): A & B & C & D;
export function extend(...args: any[]): any {
    const newObj = {};
    for (const obj of args) {
        for (const key in obj) {
            //copy all the fields
            newObj[key] = obj[key];
        }
    }
    return newObj;
};
```

## More

Both are mentioned here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-system.html

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work. However the extend() function is defined in a 3rd party library, is there any way to overwrite this specific definition for extend() in its d.ts file? (I am using underscore _.extend() ).

Comment: Yup. Just modify `underscore.d.ts`

Answer (score 12):

try this..

```
const person = { name: 'TRilok', gender: 'Male' };
const tools = { computer: 'Mac', editor: 'Atom' };
const attributes = { handsomeness: 'Extreme', hair: 'Brown', eyes: 'Blue' };

const summary = {...person, ...tools, ...attributes};
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [Typescript spread operator](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/future-javascript/spread-operator#object-spread) it transpile to Javascript Object.assign()

If you need deep tree object merging you could use changing function of [best-global](https://github.com/codenautas/best-globals) package

Comment: the spread operator is from JS not TS.

Answer (score 3):

Lodash has an "extend" function that combines objects and lets Typescirpt know that the new object has the type you'd expect.

```
const a = { one: 1, two: 2 };
const b = { three: 3, four: 4 };
const c = lodash.extend(a, b);
// c: { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4 }
```

Comment: Nice answer, thank you. "extend" of Lodash is better than merging via spread operator, because it takes properties (getters) into account!